# xslt: How could I use xslt to create a table with multiple columns and rows?

Tags: xml, xslt

How would I take this xml and create a table with a column for each "section" element and then display all the "document" elements in that column using xslt?

```
<Documents>
  <Section>
  <SectionName>Green</SectionName>
    <Document>
      <FileName>Tier 1 Schedules</FileName>     
    </Document>
    <Document>
      <FileName>Tier 3 Schedules</FileName>      
    </Document>
    <Document>
      <FileName>Setback Schedule</FileName>    
    </Document>
    <Document>
      <FileName>Tier 2 Governance</FileName>    
    </Document>
 </Section>
 <Section>
 <SectionName>MRO/Refurb</SectionName>
   <Document>
     <FileName>Tier 2 Governance</FileName>    
   </Document>
 </Section>
```

Thanks,
Al

Comment: Table? Column? They are not standard XML words. You are translating to what? XHTML?

Comment: @bortzmeyer: I think an (X)HTML table is what the OP is after.

Comment: I think you should not accept my answer just yet. I am sure if you leave the question open, better alternatives will show up.

Comment: See the solution I posted: it uses no recursion and hi-lights a few useful XSLT techniques such as Muenchian grouping, keys, finding maximum and iterating without recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
<xsl:variable name="vCountRows">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Documents/Section[1]" mode="findmax" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="vCountCols" select="count(Documents/Section)" />

<xsl:template match="/Documents">
  <table r="{$vCountRows}" s="{$vCountCols}">
    <thead>
      <xsl:call-template name="create-thead" />
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:call-template name="create-tr" />
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-thead">
   <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Section" />
  </tr>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section">
  <th><xsl:value-of select="SectionName" /></th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-tr">
  <xsl:param name="row" select="1" />

  <tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="create-td">
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </tr>

  <xsl:if test="$row &lt; $vCountRows">
    <xsl:call-template name="create-tr">
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-td">
  <xsl:param name="col" select="1" />
  <xsl:param name="row" select="1" />

  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="Section[$col]/Document[$row]/FileName" />
  </td>

  <xsl:if test="$col &lt; $vCountCols">
    <xsl:call-template name="create-td">
      <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1" />
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section" mode="findmax">
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="count(Document)" />
  <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::Section[count(Document) &gt; $c][1]" />

  <xsl:choose>    
    <xsl:when test="$next">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$next" mode="findmax" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$c" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

With your input it produces:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>MRO/Refurb</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tier 1 Schedules</td>
      <td>Tier 2 Governance</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tier 3 Schedules</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Setback Schedule</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tier 2 Governance</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The general apporach goes like this:

1. Find out how many rows we are going to get (this happens in `<xsl:template match="Section" mode="findmax">`, which recursively finds the section with the maximum number of `<Document>` nodes
2. Find out how many columns we are going to get (by counting the number of `<Section>`s)
3. calling a templates that creates a `<tr>`, and keeps calling itself until all necessary rows have been created
4. in this template, a second template is called, this one creates the `<td>`s. It keeps calling itself until it reaches the max number of columns (from step 2)

The algorithm:

- uses incrementing column- and row-numbers as indexes
- uses recursion to achieve one-by-one index increments (since actually incrementing a variable is impossible in XSLT)
- creates the right number of empty cells for sections that have less documents

A more efficient version (probably using `<xsl:key>`s) exists, I'll look into optimizing mine a little more.

Comment: Nevertheless you should wait with accepting the solution. Leave the question open overnight to attract some more responses.

Answer (score 3):

**This solution uses no recursion and hi-lights a few useful XSLT techniques such as Muenchian grouping, keys, finding maximum and iterating without recursion.**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kSectsByValue" match="SectionName"
         use="."/>

    <xsl:key name="kDocBySect" match="Document"
         use="../SectionName"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vCols" select=
       "/*/*/SectionName
                [generate-id()
                =          
                 generate-id(key('kSectsByValue',.)[1])
                 ]"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vMaxRows">
             <xsl:for-each select="$vCols">
               <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending"
                    select="count(key('kDocBySect', .))"      />
               <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                 <xsl:value-of select="count(key('kDocBySect', .))"/>
               </xsl:if>
             </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
             <table>
               <tr>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCols"/>
               </tr>

               <xsl:for-each select=
                 "(/*/*/Document)[not(position() > $vMaxRows)]">                   
                 <tr>

                   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

                   <xsl:for-each select="$vCols">
                     <td>
                       <xsl:value-of select=
                           "../Document[$vPos]/FileName"/>
                     </td>
                   </xsl:for-each>

                 </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </table>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SectionName">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </td>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the original XML document (corrected to be well-formed):**

```
<Documents>
    <Section>
        <SectionName>Green</SectionName>
        <Document>
            <FileName>Tier 1 Schedules</FileName>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <FileName>Tier 3 Schedules</FileName>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <FileName>Setback Schedule</FileName>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <FileName>Tier 2 Governance</FileName>
        </Document>
    </Section>
    <Section>
        <SectionName>MRO/Refurb</SectionName>
        <Document>
            <FileName>Tier 2 Governance</FileName>
        </Document>
    </Section>
</Documents>
```

**produces the desired result**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>MRO/Refurb</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Tier 1 Schedules</td>
      <td>Tier 2 Governance</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Tier 3 Schedules</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Setback Schedule</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Tier 2 Governance</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Do note**:

1. **We use the [Muenchian method for grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muenchian_grouping)** in order to find all different column names, not relying that in the XML document they will be unique.
2. **[Keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) are used** both for the Muenchian grouping and for finding all items belonging to a column.
3. **The maximum number of rows is found** and kept in the variable `$vMaxRows`
4. **We iterate N times** to produce the N rows of the table -- **not using recursion**!
5. **The `N`-th row is output by applying templates to all column items** that have position `N` in their column.

Comment: You solution does not currently produce the empty table cells as they are required to make a valid HTML table. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for this observation. Corrected now!

Comment: There is still a small error. Now your solution produces surplus and incorrectly nested "<td>"s.

Comment: SOrry, I have been doing thousands of other things these days. Hope that now there are no more problems.

Comment: +1 for the now working solution. I've again leaned a few things. :)

Comment: What is the reason to use "not(position() > $vMaxRows)" instead of "position() <= $vMaxRows"? Personal preference? Aesthetics? Legibility? Or something else?