# Muenchian? XSLT to denormalize/pivot/flatten xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given an input xml file with following structure:

```
<root>
  <record row="1" col="1" val="1" />
  <record row="1" col="2" val="2" />
  <record row="1" col="3" val="3" />
  <record row="1" col="n" val="4" />
  <record row="2" col="1" val="5" />
  <record row="2" col="3" val="6" />
  <record row="2" col="n" val="7" />
  <record row="n" col="2" val="8" />
  <record row="n" col="3" val="9" />
  <record row="n" col="n" val="10" />
</root>
```

How can I output the following structure using XSLT?

```
<root>
  <row id="1">
    <col id="1">1</col>
    <col id="2">2</col>
    <col id="3">3</col>
    <col id="n">4</col>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <col id="1">5</col>
    <col id="2"></col>
    <col id="3">6</col>
    <col id="n">7</col>
  </row>
  <row id="n">
    <col id="1"></col>
    <col id="2">8</col>
    <col id="3">9</col>
    <col id="n">10</col>
  </row>
</root>
```

[Note how all columns are output even if there is no related element in input]

EDIT: I may have caused confusion through the use of numbers and letters in my example.  The solution I am looking for needs to handle row and column attributes that are non-numeric.

Comment: Would you include an example that better shows your input data? If the @id attributes carry no usable value at all (in the question context at least), just leave them off.

Comment: In case column/row ids are non-numeric, there will be no need to "fill gaps", so both presented solutions will even be simpler.

Comment: You need to re-formulate your question -- best start a new question, providing the more precise definition with non-numeric id values.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Filling gaps will still be necessary for table cells, regardless of numeric or non-numeric @row/@col values. My guess is that @col values carry no more than informational value, while @row is used for grouping.

Comment: Dmitre and Tomalak - Tx, I think it will be easier to post a new question.

Comment: I'm watching out for your new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to this question show possible ways to approach the problem:

[xslt: How could I use xslt to create a table with multiple columns and rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768665/xslt-how-could-i-use-xslt-to-create-a-table-with-multiple-columns-and-rows/768909#768909)

---

EDIT: A solution that incorporates the techniques seen in the linked question follows.

I am assuming:

- your `@row` and `@col` attributes are incrementing numbers that define the position of the record in the table, and they cannot really contain the string `"n"`. As such they are not unique throughout the document, which makes them unsuitable as HTML `@id` attributes. I substituted them by `@title` attributes in my output.
- there are no implicit empty rows (gaps in `@row` continuity will not produce empty rows), only implicit empty cells.
- every `@row` and `@col` combination is unique.

This XSLT 1.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

  <!-- prepare some keys for later use -->
  <xsl:key name="kRecordsByRow" match="record" use="@row" />
  <xsl:key name="kRecordsByPos" match="record" use="concat(@row, ',', @col)" />

  <!-- find out the highest @col number -->
  <xsl:variable name="vMaxCol">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/record">
      <xsl:sort select="@col" data-type="number" order="descending" />
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="@col" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- select the <record>s that are the first in their rows -->
  <xsl:variable name="vRows" select="
    /root/record[
      generate-id()
      =
      generate-id(key('kRecordsByRow', @row)[1])
    ]
  " />  

  <!-- output basic table structure -->
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="$vRows">
        <xsl:sort select="@row" data-type="number" />
        <tr title="{@row}">
          <xsl:call-template name="td" />
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- output the right number of <td>s in each row, empty or not -->
  <xsl:template name="td">
    <xsl:param name="col" select="1" />

    <td title="{$col}">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('kRecordsByPos', concat(@row, ',', $col))/@val" />
    </td>

    <xsl:if test="$col &lt; $vMaxCol">
      <xsl:call-template name="td">
        <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

…when applied to this (slightly modified) input:

```
<root>
  <record row="1" col="1" val="1" />
  <record row="1" col="2" val="2" />
  <record row="1" col="3" val="3" />
  <record row="1" col="4" val="4" />
  <record row="2" col="1" val="5" />
  <record row="2" col="3" val="6" />
  <record row="2" col="4" val="7" />
  <record row="3" col="2" val="8" />
  <record row="3" col="3" val="9" />
  <record row="3" col="4" val="10" />
</root>
```

…produces:

```
<table>
  <tr title="1">
    <td title="1">1</td>
    <td title="2">2</td>
    <td title="3">3</td>
    <td title="4">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="2">
    <td title="1">5</td>
    <td title="2"></td>
    <td title="3">6</td>
    <td title="4">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="3">
    <td title="1"></td>
    <td title="2">8</td>
    <td title="3">9</td>
    <td title="4">10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- Muenchian grouping is used to select the first `<record>`s of each `@row` group
- an `<xsl:key>` is used to pinpoint a record by it's position
- recursion is used to produce a consistent set of `<td>`s, independent of the actual existence of a `<record>` at the named position

Comment: A very nice and complete solution! I don't have anything to add to it. :)

Comment: Thank you. :-) (I guess I could have used the "iterating without recursion" technique I learned from your answer in the question I linked).

Comment: Tomalak - Thank you for the solution; however, I may have caused confusion through the use of numbers and letters in my example.  The solution I am looking for needs to handle row and column attributes that are non-numeric.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer in the question I linked to? The XSLT there does just that.

Comment: I did but am confused by the location path patterns.  I am going to post a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it was very helpful and although it didn't answer my question completely the fault was my wording in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**An XSLT 2.0 solution**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    >

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc" as="document-node()"
     select="/"/>

    <xsl:key name="kColsByRow" match="@col" 
         use="../@row"/>

    <xsl:key name="kRecByRowCol" match="record" 
         use="concat(@row,'+',@col)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*/@row" 
             group-by=".">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"
               data-type="number"/>

           <xsl:variable name="vRow" 
                select="current-grouping-key()"/>  

           <row idd="{$vRow}">

              <xsl:for-each select=
               "1 to max(key('kColsByRow',$vRow)/xs:integer(.))">

                <col idd="{.}">
                  <xsl:value-of select=
                  "key('kRecByRowCol',
                        concat($vRow,'+',.),
                        $vDoc
                       )
                       /
                        @col
                "
                  />
                </col>
              </xsl:for-each>
           </row>    
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<root>
    <record row="1" col="1" val="1" />
    <record row="1" col="2" val="2" />
    <record row="1" col="3" val="3" />
    <record row="1" col="10" val="4" />
    <record row="2" col="1" val="5" />
    <record row="2" col="3" val="6" />
    <record row="2" col="10" val="7" />
    <record row="10" col="2" val="8" />
    <record row="10" col="3" val="9" />
    <record row="10" col="10" val="10" />
</root>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<root>
   <row idd="1">
      <col idd="1">1</col>
      <col idd="2">2</col>
      <col idd="3">3</col>
      <col idd="4"/>
      <col idd="5"/>
      <col idd="6"/>
      <col idd="7"/>
      <col idd="8"/>
      <col idd="9"/>
      <col idd="10">10</col>
   </row>
   <row idd="2">
      <col idd="1">1</col>
      <col idd="2"/>
      <col idd="3">3</col>
      <col idd="4"/>
      <col idd="5"/>
      <col idd="6"/>
      <col idd="7"/>
      <col idd="8"/>
      <col idd="9"/>
      <col idd="10">10</col>
   </row>
   <row idd="10">
      <col idd="1"/>
      <col idd="2">2</col>
      <col idd="3">3</col>
      <col idd="4"/>
      <col idd="5"/>
      <col idd="6"/>
      <col idd="7"/>
      <col idd="8"/>
      <col idd="9"/>
      <col idd="10">10</col>
   </row>
</root>
```